# Css div fill parent height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">
    item 1
  <div>
  <div class="item-2">
    item 2
  <div>
</div>
```

wherefore I created the following codepen example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWXpVV

At the top of the parent div I want to place the blue div. The remaining height of the parent div should be filled with the second child div (red one).

How can I achieve that the height of the red div completely covers the area of ​​the parent div?

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">
    item 1
  <div>
  <div class="item-2">
    item 2
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: "wherefore" ... love it. First time I see that word on this site. Commonly found in US founding documents and Shakespeare. Nice!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on the parent, and `flex-grow: 1` on the element you want to consume the rest of the available space. You also need to properly close your `div` elements with `</div>`

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    item 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution this is exactly what worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: blue;  
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: red;  
  height: 100%;
}  

<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    item 2
 </div>
</div>
```